# Moving through different path with the same key in BGE

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm trying to create a rail with multiple paths, but not at the same point, like, using left/right arrow:

```
         0
         |
         1
        / \
       2   3
      /\   /\
     4  5 6  7
```

Right now, I'm using only keyboard sensors assigned to a steering actuators.
The problem is: the game loses itself when over the 2 and 3 points. If I press left or right, it doesn't know witch path the object should go.
I have 4 navigation meshes that goes from 0~4, 0~5, 0~6, 0~7 and 7 targets.

I'm trying to figure that out using the logic bricks, because I know nothing about python.